# Change a content language

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Can someone tell me please how could I change a content language?
I created my basic pages in the frensh default language, now i would like to make english as my site default language, but i lost all my pages linked to the menu I had .

Thank you

===============Sorry I can't post answers:

Thanks every body for your ansewrs. In fact when i ckecked it again the probleme was in the url alias when the menu link point on a page which i made an alias it does not work it redirect me to an empty page

Comment: Can you post your code please, it's hard to help without it

Comment: Thanks every body for your ansewrs. In fact when i ckecked it again the probleme was in the url alias when the menu link point on a page which i made an alias it does not work it redirect me to an empty page

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use Drupal's built in Locale module and then Internationalization module. http://drupal.org/project/i18n

Answer (score 0):

You must put an english page as a frontpage ;-) then the english menu will be launch!

Answer (score 0):

a new menu english is made when you create english language. this menu is linked with a node with the language english... recreate the menu-links, you have no chois, it is the default with drupal ...

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to enable the Multilingual support in the content types I had including the basic pages attched to my menu, and change the language of every single node I had, it's long but it did it,
Thank you all very much.